# Receive notification on any data change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to display a JSON view of the current data. How shall I go about it? I thought to register a function that receives a notification on any data change, and then just put the JSON text in a text field.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply output the field, Vue's reactive so the updates will be reflected:

```
<pre>{{ yourJSON }}</pre>
```

Or if you are referring to the components data object:

```
<pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
```

If you need to do more then use a computed property